# Changing size of globe in Leaflet globe mini map?

Tags: leaflet

This plugin fits all my needs but I can't figure out how to change the size of the globe in the example to 175px width and height.
https://github.com/chriswhong/leaflet-globeminimap

I tried this in the settings but it did not work:

```
var miniMap = new L.Control.GlobeMiniMap({
  position: 'bottomright',
  width: 175,
  height: 175,
  land:'#d9d9d9',
  water:'#e9eef9',
  marker:'#418fde',
  topojsonSrc : 'world.json'
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you supply seems correct to me. Not familiar with the plugin but looking through the source code I think the size might be hard coded, despite suggesting it can be set with an option. Look at lines [70 & 71 of the source](https://github.com/chriswhong/leaflet-globeminimap/blob/master/src/Control.GlobeMiniMap.js) and you will see the `svg` has size 82x82. The options you specify set the containing `div` element's size (lines 39 & 40).

I think this may be a quick fix by substituting in `this.option.width/height` at lines 70 & 71, but it may(?) mess up the path that creates the world boundary. Why they aren't just using a `circle` element is confusing to me.

You could submit an issue and maybe the plugin maintainers will add this feature.